# Zip files in .net core with password

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, compression

I'm trying to generate zip (or other compression formats) files in **.net core** with password, but I can't find any tool that does not come without a cost.

I've tried `System.IO.Compression` but it doesn't have a method with password.

Comment: Zip is an open format and there are several free implementations for .net (try dotnetzip) that support encryption. Rar and 7z are proprietary, I don't know of any free libraries that support them since they must be licensed.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I need it for **.net Core**, dotnetzip supports .net framework but didn't support .net Core. I'm going to edit my question to be clearer

Comment: Thanks, but that work on _.Net Framework_, i'm using **.net Core**, and i can't found any like `dotnetzip` for **.net Core**

Comment: @Johna, what did you end up doing?

Comment: @R4nc1d Unfortunately I could not do it. I ended up signing the documents inside the zip to check its integrity, but I could not protect the zip with password.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using SharpZipLib, not ideal but it works well

Comment: @R4nc1d - can you share your code for .net core with Sharpziplib?

Comment: @Neel, please see below answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `SharpZipLib.NETStandard` [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpZipLib.NETStandard/) package.

```
public async Task<byte[]> ZipAsync(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Stream>> files, string mime, string password)
{
    ExceptionHelper.ThrowIfNull(nameof(files), files);
    ExceptionHelper.ThrowIfNull(nameof(mime), mime);

    using (var output = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(output))
        {
            zipStream.SetLevel(9);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                zipStream.Password = password;
            }

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var newEntry = new ZipEntry($"{file.Key}.{mime}") { DateTime = DateTime.Now };
                zipStream.PutNextEntry(newEntry);

                await file.Value.CopyToAsync(zipStream);
                zipStream.CloseEntry();
            }
        }

        return output.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. Btw memory stream may cause an issue if the files are large?,

Comment: @Neel, yea we have a limit of 8MB, MemoryStream will load the entire file into memory. If I had to use download larger files I would most prob just use a Stream. But i think you know that already :-)

Comment: Thanks. 8 MB is fine, yes you are right. It would load the entire file into the memory. For .Net Core, this solution works well for large files: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/11/streaming-zip-on-aspnet-core.html

Comment: You will need add the namespace ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip to run this code.

Answer (score 3):

Good news is that `DotNetZip` supports .net Core now. Check [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/1.16.0) for more details.
(Meanwhile System.IO.Compression still doesn't support password protection)

I've used 1.16.0 version in .Net Core 3.1 and it works well.

*Brief tutorial:*

```
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    zip.Password = pwd;
                    zip.AddEntry(FileA_Name, FileA_Content);
                    zip.AddEntry(FileB_Name, FileB_Content);
                    MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
                    zip.Save(output);
                    return File(output.ToArray(), "application/zip", Zip_Name);
                }
```

Don't forget to add DotNetZip Nuget package in your project, and import `using Ionic.Zip;`

Comment: Wow, fantastic news, thanks @亞鯉斯多德 for share this